# Is it possible to cut long variable name if it is too long?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a long named variable, is it possible to cut it, like in a half for example?

```
aquiredCostsOfIncomeInSamePlaceOfLiveAndWorkPersonUnderTwentySixNotAStudent = 250
```

I have tried and it doesn't work:

1. Backslash:

   ```
   aquiredCostsOfIncomeInSamePlaceOf\
   LiveAndWorkPersonUnderTwentySixNotAStudent = 250
   ```
2. Backslash and parentheses:

   ```
   (aquiredCostsOfIncomeInSamePlaceOf\
   LiveAndWorkPersonUnderTwentySixNotAStudent = 250)
   ```
3. Plus:

   ```
   aquiredCostsOfIncomeInSamePlaceOf+
   LiveAndWorkPersonUnderTwentySixNotAStudent = 250
   ```
4. Parentheses and quotes:

   ```
   ('aquiredCostsOfIncomeInSamePlaceOfLive
   AndWorkPersonUnderTwentySixNotAStudent') = 250
   ```
5. Parentheses and more quotes:

   ```
   ('aquiredCostsOfIncomeInSamePlaceOf'
   'LiveAndWorkPersonUnderTwentySixNotAStudent') = 250
   ```

The only thing I found that worked was:

```
aquiredCostsOfIncomeInSamePlaceOfLiveAndWorkPersonUnderTwentySixNotAStudent\ 
= 250
```

but I could always cut after the "=" brackets.

Do you know any solution?

Comment: This is not possible. I think you should seriously rethink your strategy of choosing variable names :)

Comment: You should use much shorter variable names, but use context to derive extra meaning.

Comment: Variable names should NOT be essays.

Comment: A variable name THAT long is only possible in some parts of Wales! Seriously, try to go for something MUCH shorter.

Comment: How about just reassigning it to some initials or something shorter and use the new short variable ej:   x = aquiredCostsOfIncomeInSamePlaceOfLiveAndWorkPersonUnderTwentySixNotAStudent

Answer (score 0):

There is one way but not recommended:

```
globals()["aquiredCostsOfIncomeInSamePlaceOfLive" + \
"AndWorkPersonUnderTwentySixNotAStudent"] = 250

print(aquiredCostsOfIncomeInSamePlaceOfLiveAndWorkPersonUnderTwentySixNotAStudent)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: There is another way but it is even more not recommended - use `exec`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this, but not in the traditional way: use a dictionary.

```py
my_vars = {
'aquiredCostsOfIncome' \
'InSamePlaceOfLiveAnd'\
'WorkPersonUnderTwentySix'\
'NotAStudent': 250
}
print(my_vars['aquiredCostsOfIncomeInSamePlaceOfLiveAndWorkPersonUnderTwentySixNotAStudent'])
```

(Note: do not do this. Just make a shorter name)